# getElements is not a supported property or method in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mootools

I have a JavaScript issue when the page is viewed in IE only. I get this:

> object doesn't support this property or method

The line in my JavaScript code that generates this error is:

```
var panels = $('collapser').getElements('div.menuTable');
```

The above code is trying to get all div elements with the class `menuTable` within the `collapser` element.

Seems like IE doesn't like the `getElements` method!

Here's is the relevant part of the page in HTML:

```
<div id="collapser" class="text2"> 
    <h2 class="menu">system features1</h2> 
    <div id="div145fgjd584rgd" class="menuTable">
     ...
    </div>
    <h2 class="menu">system features2</h2> 
    <div id="div2sf54685454rtyt" class="menuTable">
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did any other browser support this JAVA script???

Comment: Genrally there's nothing wrong with your code. I'm sure that if you run this snippet in JsFiddle and view it under IE, it'll work just fine. That said, your problem might be caused by some other code you have embedded. Be sure, you do `console.log(document.id('collapser'))` to check if the element gets properly fetched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in IE 6, 7 and 8(in part), the Element.prototype is verbotten or elements just don't benefit from changes to their prototype.

As a workaround, MooTools add copies all `Element.prototype` methods to each IE element object when it gets accessed through a selector ($, $$) or when it is being created (Element constructor).

Basically: `$("collapser")` or `document.id("collapser")` or `new Element('div#collapser')` will also copy the methods and setup element storage etc--it's a one-off operation.

Which leads me to believe that the `$()` function that you have is NOT the mootools one.

For example:

```
this.$ = document.getElementById;
$("collapser").getElements("div"); // exception in IE6/7/8
```

what version of mootools is it? `console.log($);` // is it the mootools one?

you can also do:

```
var panels = document.getElements('#collapser div.menuTable');
```

Comment: One small comment about that last one. You could write it as `panels = $$('#collapser div.menuTable');`. Though, I do agree with the fact that there is something wrong with his $-function. If this problem is IE-only I'd say it's rewritten, else maybe he added another framework that use the $, like, say, jQuery?

Comment: `$$` used to actually be an alias for `document.getElements` and now they both rely on `Slick.search` anyway.

Comment: I know, it's just that afaik, $$ is the API-documented way to do it. http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollars

Comment: Thank you Dimitar, I've briefly tested this with your option:      var panels = document.getElements('#collapser div.menuTable'); and it looks to have solved the problem.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff Thank you for this answer.  I ran into this issue under different circumstances so I'll drop a comment for future users.  I had code that worked fine anywhere but IE and the reason was that I used `.parentNode` on an element already passed through mootools $ (e.g. `$$('.element').parentNode`).  The properties do not apply to the parent in that situation so you need to wrap it (`$($$('.element').parentNode)`).  I also had to change a `document.createElement("div")` to `$(document.createElement("div"))`.  Stupid mistakes, but thanks for the informative answer, Dimitar.

Comment: use the API and you won't go wrong. `document.createElement('div')` -> `new Element('div')` -> it extends the element created and sets up element uid/storage. plus a bunch of sugary constructor options. if you deal with plain objects, you can always pass through $ like so: `$(element.parentNode);` -> will extend so it guarantees methods to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code with:

var ie8 = jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version == "8.0";
var panels = (ie8 ? $('collapser').document : $('collapser')).getElements('div.menuTable');

Cheers!